# Programmers SE Menu - Whitespace Doesn't Link

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the Programmers SE site, the menu (with links to Questions, Tags, ect) has a line drawn and text changed to red (or gray in meta) when hovering over that menu item. However, the user must hover over the text in the menu item to actually be able to click on the link.

Ergo, if the user hovers over the non-text part (such as the drawn line), there is no active link.

Is this a bug in the way the css is designed for that SE? On all other SE sites, if the menu item changes (when hovering), I know I can click to go to that page; I don't have to hover over the actual text.

**Edit**: The designers have partially fixed this, but not fully. The whitespace and line directly below the text is clickable, but if you move your mouse to the left or right of the text, the hover effect is active but no link is clickable.

Comment: For the sites that don't have a simple text as the menu, it doesn't seem to be consistent.  GIS has the same issue as Programmers, but Mathematics doesn't.  Having said that, most of the SE sites employ simple text as the menu.

Comment: @Walter I wasn't able to get the same affect on GIS as here.

Comment: I'm bugged by this too. I don't so much care about the whitespace being/not being a link as the inconsistency of the hover effect; hover effect should = link. Whether the whitespace links or not is a design choice (one which could go either way and make sense here, as long as hover effects are consistent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy, in so far as is possible across all browsers.

Basically, you'll be able to click on the underlines directly underneath the words (and in the whitespace between them).

Comment: This is mostly fixed now, but you can still activate the hover effect without having a clickable link if you have your mouse to the left or right of the text. Personally, I think that it should be clickable *anytime* the hover effect activates.